# QueryDSL - Compare only date from dateTime

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

Is there any way to compare only the date portion of dateTime field? I know I could use between with begin and end of day but that isn't pretty. Neither compare each field (day, month, year...);

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetrunc` method ([doc here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.7/apidocs/com/querydsl/sql/SQLExpressions.html#datetrunc-com.querydsl.sql.DatePart-com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.DateTimeExpression-)).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Expressions` class. In this case it is possible to use `Expressions::dateTimeOperation` and `Ops.DateTimeOps.DATE` to truncate the time part:

```
import com.querydsl.core.BooleanBuilder;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Ops;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.*;

...

public Iterable<Entity> getList(Date createdOn) {

    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    BooleanExpression compareDatePart = Expressions.dateTimeOperation(
                Date.class, Ops.DateTimeOps.DATE,
                QEntity.entity.timestamp).eq(createdOn);
    Predicate predicate = builder.and(compareDatePart).getValue();
 
    return entityRepository.findAll(predicate);
}

...
```